# Will upgrading my iPod touch 3g erase any data or settings?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, ipod, ios

My old iPod nano was completely erased, (losing some unrecoverable songs) when I last updated iPod firmware. Is there a way to upgrade my iPod touch 3g without losing all my data?

Comment: I just updated a iPod touch and it all worked without losing music or photos

Answer (score 2):

iTunes should back up the data before updating the firmware and restore it again afterwards (this is what it does with an iPhone)

To be absolutely sure you can right click on the iPod Touch in the tree and select Backup to create a manual one before updating.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade should be seamless however the iPhone 3G experiences some serious lag with ios 4.  Rumour is that stuff is better with the upcoming ios 4.1.  I assume the same holds for the touch.